# Does Service Bus for Windows Server (Service Bus 1.0 Beta) support REST API?

Tags: rest, servicebus

IF support where can i find detail documentation about REST api.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The protocol surface between Server and Service is largely symmetric, albeit there are different ports for some sub-services and the authentication model has been adapted for a Server environment using a local STS instead of ACS. You will find updated MSDN documentation beyond what's currently available as part of the SDK as we ship the release version of Service Bus Server, which will happen before this month is over.

Answer (score 3):

THanks for the reply and Update information about release version of service bus. i manage to sucessfully connect to the service bus and get the authentication token using following microsoft examples.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj193003%28v=azure.10%29.aspx

Once u get the token rest of operation (create que, send messages, recive messages) are same as windows azure service bus. please see the detail about microsoft documentation about service bus operation.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh690927.aspx
hope this helpful.
THanks.